# Connecting SQL server 2000 using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2000

I'm facing following issue using Visual Studio 2012 when I'm trying to connect with MS SQL Server 2000 (in Data Connections window):

[image]

Strange is that it's actually getting list of databases when I'm using Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient) as a data source.

Is there any way to connect VS 2012 and SQL Server 2000? Should I use different driver/provider? Is it possible at all to use those technologies together?

Comment: I'm sorry I've just used .NET Framework Data Provder for OLE DB -> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server and it't working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. .NET Framework Data Provder for OLE DB -> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL must be used.