# Incompatible MS SQL server version with devexpress version 15.x

Tags: visual-studio-2012, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to add a Project Data Source in a GridView in DevExpress.
I click on the little arrow on the above right of the Gridview.  I choose 'Add project Data Source'.
Then I choose, a Data Type source => DATABASE. 
Then, 'Database model' =>DATASET.
Then, for 'Data connection' I choose MS SQL Server.
I then choose the server and I get a pop-up windows that says:

This server version is not supported.  You must have SQL Server 2005 or later.

Now, I've confirmed that the server I'm trying to connect to has Microsoft SQL Server 2000 installed on it.

I know that some people got that pop-up window when trying to use Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  It was apparently a Visual Studio issue.

I just want to confirm that this message that I'm getting is legit.  (It would seem right, seeing, as I
mentionned earlier, I have Microsoft SQL Server 2000 installed.  ) For some reason, I still
think it's weird that I'm getting this message.  I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 by the way. Can anybody confirm this.  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that this issue is related to DevExpress control. It is common issue with visual studio when you SQL Server that Visual studio IDE does not support or missing SQL Server Data Objects.

I suggest you to check below link for your confirmation that SQL Server is not supported in newer IDE directly.

[This server version is not supported. You must have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Beta 2 or later.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1869061.aspx?This%20server%20version%20is%20not%20supported%20You%20must%20have%20Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202005%20Beta%202%20or%20later%20)
[SQL Server 2000 and Visual Studio 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37d137be-f119-4d49-bddf-99f398328096/sql-server-2000-and-visual-studio-2010?forum=vstsdb)
[This Server Version is not supported. You must have SQL 2005 or later (VS2010 Problem)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633380/this-server-version-is-not-supported-you-must-have-sql-2005-or-later-vs2010-problem)

Some how you can use quick fix to connect with the data base and write code to do other operations.
[Connecting SQL server 2000 using Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476957/connecting-sql-server-2000-using-visual-studio-2012)

```
.NET Framework Data Provder for OLE DB -> Microsoft OLE DB Provider
```

Hope this help you understand the real issue behind this.